# Search remote malware zoo for homologous samples

Tags: binary-analysis, malware

I've got the following problem:

I'd like to find new binaries of a certain malware family -- unpacked -- for subsequent analysis (active C&C comms analysis).

Is there a database of binaries somewhere where I can write a query like the following:

Give me samples that are homologous to an input binary (or collection thereof) using fuzzy hashing as the distance metric and then filter by date seen?

To clarify, the samples don't use packing.

Comment: AV companies (and some security companies) spend a large amount of resources creating these databases. I know of no public system that allows you to search for homologous samples using just a sample (or set of samples) as input. You may want to search based on strings in your sample, and if you don't find anything with that approach, reach out to friends in the AV industry to see if they can help you find related samples.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that most of these databases aren't public, the malware analysis companies tries to keep it for them.

Yet, I recommend you to take a look at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) (see its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirusTotal) for more information about it) which is probably the most furnished database available on-line.

You may also want to take a look at the [IRMA](http://irma.quarkslab.com/) (Incident Response Malware Analysis) framework if you want to run your own server.

Finally, here is a collection of tools and papers on methods to find similarities in binary blobs:

- [`sdhash`](http://roussev.net/sdhash/sdhash.html) tool (see also this [blog post](http://www.cybercrimetech.com/2012/09/similarity-comparison-with-sdhash-fuzzy.html));
- [`ssdeep`](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/) tool;
- [BinSlayer: Accurate Comparison of Binary Executables](http://kar.kent.ac.uk/37627/1/a4-bourquin.pdf), by Bourquin, King and Robbins , 2013 ([GitHub Project](https://github.com/MartialB/BinSlayer));
- [mvHash - a new approach for fuzzy hashing](http://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/144008/KPAstebol.pdf), by Knut Petter Åstebø, 2012;
- [An evaluation of forensic similarity hashes](http://dfrws.org/2011/proceedings/09-341.pdf), by Vassil Roussev, 2011.

This list is far from being complete, but I think that this is a good starting point...

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 2):

VirusTotal has import hash to match:
http://blog.virustotal.com/2014/02/virustotal-imphash.html

Comment: In fact, imphash (Import Hashing) correspond just to the hash of the import table of the executable. It is a good signature for software using an unusual set of API functions, but if you manage to use only very common ones you will remain unnoticed. Better than the link you gave, prefer [this one](https://www.mandiant.com/blog/tracking-malware-import-hashing/) (much more detailed).

Answer (score 1):

I work on the team for [darkpoint](http://darkpoint.us).  Our platform can compare and cluster submitted malware based on feature vectors.  Basically, we do static and dynamic analysis to determine the characteristics of all the software we see.  Then we use machine learning to discover matches.  You can also do explicit matches based on normal search terms.

Answer (score 1):

malshare.com - Request an API Key and pull all the samples you want.